# SSDT transactional publish?

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

Using msbuild with SSDT, I have tried IncludeTransactionalScripts, but it seems to only put each statement in an individual transaction.
Is it possible to publish multiple database projects as a transaction?
If not, can I at least make sure that each Project is published within a transaction?

Comment: I think it does that right now if you choose that option. It checks after each operation for an error and if it finds one issues a ROLLBACK for everything done in the schema change portion. (Pre and post deploy sections are separate and outside of this.)

Comment: Are you sure? Looking at the script it generates multiple BEGIN and COMMIT transactions, like every change is in its own transaction. I'd like one big transaction for the lot. Of course it might be impractical if there is a lot of change, but sometimes it can be useful.

Comment: It definitely rolls back everything in the schema change portion if there's an error. I know this from painfully trying to push just a portion of the DB project when I had dependencies on a yet-to-be-created DB/table. Look for the "IF @@ERROR <> 0" sections in the script and you shouldn't see multiple commits, just rollbacks.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I will have to try to make an 'outer transaction' to handle pre/post scripts as well.

Comment: Best bet there is likely to handle a version or dependency of some sort, maybe a "Begin Tran" in Pre-deploy and "Commit/Rollback" in post-deploy. I don't know of a way to tie the three sections together so _everything_ succeeds or fails natively. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anybody else who found this question, but didn't know where to look:

There is a publish setting, "Include transactional scripts", that begins a transaction at the start of the publish script. It then wraps each schema change in the script in an error check. On errors, the transaction is rolled back and an error log is incremented, but then the transaction is started from scratch. If there is no error, the transaction continues *uncommitted*

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

...alter object here

IF @@ERROR <> 0  @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
    VALUES                 (1);
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
END
```

At the end, if errors have been registered, the whole transaction is rolled back:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
```

---

Note (as in the comments above) that this doesn't include your pre-/post-deployment scripts, so you should be careful to wrap these separately

---

The link below is to Peter Schott's blog - it's same guy who commented above I think - thanks :)

http://schottsql.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/ssdt-publishing-your-project.html

He explains nicely how to configure these settings when using SSMS

---

Using Visual Studio 2015, I found that the "Include transactional scripts" setting was not set by default. You have to select this when defining the Publish settings ([Build]>>[Publish {project name} ...]) under the [Advanced...] tab:

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks , is there anyway to wrap the transaction in (predeployment+dacpac+postdeployment) as one transaction ?